# Naming the outputs of a pop vs a shift operation on a sequence of elements

Tags: containers, sequence, terminology

I'm defining a push and a shift operation in some programming-language-like project of mine (which is irrelevant to this question) - on an ordered finite sequence of elements. Their semantics will be:

- **Shift**: Remove the first element from the sequence (so the second element becomes the first, third becomes second etc.).
- **Pop**: Remove the last element from the sequence (so that all elements except the last maintain their relative positions).

For **Shift**, I can name the element removed the "head", and the rest of the sequence the "tail". But what about **Pop**? Should I also use these two names, or is there another fitting combination I could use for differentiation?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a *[circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)*. (except that it is an open ended, two way circular buffer)

So, borrowing from terms typically used to define parts of a circular buffer, would it not be natural to refer to the regions of your storage object as:

> *head* - One end of the object
>   *tail* - The other end of the object
>   *buffer* - The data stored in the object

For the verbs, since you can push (or pop) from either end, 4 phrases are needed:

> *forward push* (push from the head)
>   *reverse push* (push from the tail)
>   *forward pop* (pop from the head)
>   *reverse pop* (pop from the tail)

With the regions of your storage object defined, it should be sufficient to refer to the data object placed into either end by the region itself. i.e the *new tail*, or the *new head*.

[image]

As for removed data, I am not sure what purpose a *name* would serve, as once a data item has been removed it's affiliation with the storage buffer ceases to exist.